# How to initiate R plotly chart with only some values visible

Tags: r, plotly

I am keen to be able to initially just show points from a selected set of values of a variable. So, in the example below, just show team values 'a' initially with the 'b' in legend greyed-out but togglable

```
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(year=(c(2000,2001,2001,2002)),team=c("a","b","a","b"),values=c(1,3,2,4),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

plot_ly(data=df, x=year,y=values,color=team,mode="markers")
```

[image]

Also, how can the axes just show whole numbers - not sure how to amend the range to cater for this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplest is to start with all the traces turned off by default, and switch them individually by clicking on the legend

```
plot_ly(data=df, x=year,y=values,color=team,mode="markers", visible="legendonly")
```

If you want to start with some points already visible and the others off, you'll need to use two traces, the second one with `visible="legendonly"`. If you do it this way, you'll also need to choose the colors manually.

```
plot_ly(data=df[which(df$team=="a"),], x=year,y=values,
        color=team, colors = "blue", mode="markers") %>%
  add_trace(data=df[which(df$team=="b"),], x=year,y=values, color=team, 
        colors="green", mode="markers", visible="legendonly")
```

You control the axes and ticks using the `layout` function. To put ticks only at unit intervals you can use this

```
plot_ly(data=df[df$team=="a",], x=year,y=values,color=team, colors = "blue", mode="markers") %>%
  add_trace(data=df[df$team=="b",], x=year,y=values, color=team, colors = "green", mode="markers", visible="legendonly") %>%
  layout(xaxis = list(autotick = FALSE, tickmode="linear", tick0 =2000, dtick=1, range=c(1999.5,2003.5)), 
         yaxis = list(autotick = FALSE, tickmode="linear", tick0 =0, dtick=1, range=c(0,5)) )
```

A full description of all options in the plotly API can be found at https://plot.ly/r/reference/

Comment: Thank you very much for answer to both issues. i have just sent edit as your final code did not specify data.frame in bracket i.e.needs to be df$team rather than team